# My Wordpress is completely broken in Safari

Tags: macos, wordpress, safari

In Safari 5.1.2 on OSX 
[Tech.li](http://www.tech.li/) is completely broken.

Some people mentioned an extra div tag being the cause, but that still didn't fix the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try validating your markup http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 3):

Pretty basic: fix your xhtml errors [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  tech.li  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//tech.li/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654) (scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code). And use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or in Chrome or Safari or IE8, use the developer tools to find and fix the javascript errors.